# How to specify language in xml comment <code> tag

Tags: c#, xml, xml-comments

Is there a way to specify what language is being used in the `<code>` tag used within an `<example>` tag in XML comments?

I am using Sandcastle Help File Builder to test building documentation from my XML comments, but when I include VB.net code samples in my example sections, it displays them as "C#", not vb.net.  Not sure if there is something else I need to do...

Here is the XML comments I am trying to make.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates and sends an email.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="subject">A <c>String</c> that contains the subject text.</param>
        /// <param name="emailBody">A <c>String</c> that contains the message body.</param>
        /// <param name="emailFrom">A <c>String</c> that contains the address of the sender of the e-mail message.</param>
        /// <param name="emailTo">A <c>String</c> that contains the addresses of the recipients of the e-mail messa</param>
        /// <param name="emailBCC">The email address to blind carbon-copy the email to.</param>
        /// <param name="IsHtml">if set to <c>true</c> [the body of the email HTML].</param>
        /// <param name="attachment">The <c>System.Net.Mail.Attachment</c> to the email.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><c>emailFrom</c> is null or <c>emailTo</c> is null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"><c>emailFrom</c> is <c>Empty</c> ("") or <c>emailTo</c> is <c>Empty</c> ("").</exception>
        /// <example>
        /// <code>
        /// string subject = "This is my subject.";
        /// string[] emailBody = new {"body line 1", "body line 2"};
        /// string emailFrom = "test@test.com";
        /// string emailTo = "recipient@test.com";
        /// string emailBCC = string.empty;
        /// bool isHTML = false;
        /// 
        /// EmailWithComments.SendEmail(subject, emailBody, emailFrom, emailTo, emailBCC, isHTML, null);
        /// </code>
        /// <code>
        /// Dim subject As String = "This is my subject."
        /// Dim emailBody As String() = New From { _
        ///     "body line 1", _
        ///     "body line 2" _
        /// }
        /// Dim emailFrom As String = "test@test.com"
        /// Dim emailTo As String = "recipient@test.com"
        /// Dim emailBCC As String = String.empty
        /// Dim isHTML As Boolean = False
        ///
        /// EmailWithComments.SendEmail(subject, emailBody, emailFrom, emailTo, emailBCC, isHTML, Nothing)
        /// </code>
        /// </example>
```

Comment: In case you don't already know http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx seems to be documentation for the XML. Neither `code` nor `example` seem to have any options to set language so I suspect you may be out of luck. :(

Comment: Ya, I was looking there and didn't see it.  Was trying to figure out how MSDN can make examples for different programming languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sandcastle Help File Builder [extends the code tag](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/7f03ba39-09f8-4320-bdbd-ed31a3bd885f.htm) and supports the `lang` attribute.

Comment: To expand this from a link-only answer: in this case it would be `<code language="cs">` … `<code>`

Comment: And <code language="VB.NET">… <code>